# Find out the Date Gap Excel

Tags: excel, date

I have a date column like so:

```
Date
----------
01/01/2011
02/01/2011
03/01/2011
04/01/2011
05/01/2011
20/01/2011
21/01/2011
22/01/2011
23/01/2011
```

As you can see there is a gap of 15 days missing, how I can find out that I have a gap with either conditional formatting or a formula.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using conditional formatting

1. Highlight A3:A100
2. Apply the CF Formula        **=AND(A4>0,A4-A3>1)**

[image]